# AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'

Tags: python, email, timestamp, dataset

My Code:

```
dfs['dayofweek'] = dfs['date'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday_name)
dfs['dayofweek'] = pd.Categorical(dfs['dayofweek'], categories=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',     
'Thursday', 'Friday','Saturday', 'Sunday'], ordered=True)`
```

Error in code:

```
 AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`day_name()` to display `weekday_name`

https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1304

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `apply` but the vectorial [`dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) method:

```
dfs['dayofweek'] = dfs['date'].dt.day_name()
```

If you're unsure whether `date` is already in the correct type, first run [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
dfs['dayofweek'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs['date'], errors='coerce').dt.day_name()
```